# Send multiple files with S3TransferManager without physical directory

Tags: java, kotlin, amazon-s3

Does anyone know how can I send multiple files (as a file list `MutableList<File>` that I populate within a loop) using the `S3TransferManager` method `uploadDirectory` without needing to create the files physically on my disc?
It does't need to use `uploadDirectory` method, but I don't want to save them on disc before send them to S3, I have them on memory and I'd like o keep it that way. Here is my code block so far:

```
val s3Request = PutObjectRequest.builder()
            .bucket(bucket)
            .key(s3Key)
            .contentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
            .build()
val tm = S3TransferManager.create()
// sending only one file
val upload = tm.uploadFile { b -> b.source(createFileFromBytes(file)).putObjectRequest(s3Request) }
upload.completionFuture().join()

...
// is there something like (supose my fileMutableList already have all the files I want to send)
val uploads = tm.uploadFiles { b -> b.source(fileMutableList).putObjectsRequest(s3Request) }
uploads.completionFuture().join()
...
```

I'm using the `software.amazon.awssdk:s3-transfer-manager:2.17.123-PREVIEW` lib for Java on my Kotlin project, which you can find out more about it [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/introducing-amazon-s3-transfer-manager-in-the-aws-sdk-for-java-2-x/).

Any thoughts are very appreciated.